# Can anyone explain and trace this because my teacher can't

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, trace

the question in the exam was :

write the output of the following program :

```
int i = 2 ;
int main () {

    int j = 10, p ;
    while (i-- && p == fork())
        if ( p < 0 ) exit(1);
    j += 2;
    if (p == 0) {
        i *= 3;
        j *= 3;
    }
    else {
        i *= 2;
        j *= 2;
    }

    printf("i = %d, j = %d \n",i,j);

    return 0;
}
```

Output from the console using xcode with include this lines before `int i = 2;` :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
```

**Output:**

```
i = 3, j = 36 
i = 0, j = 36 
i = -3, j = 36
```

Note: I notice that the output is different if we use the Ubuntu.

i think this is the output of the Ubuntu :

```
i = 2 , j = 24
i = 2 , j = 24
```

any brief explain or trace would be great Thanks

Comment: I'd expect a teacher to catch an issue like this.  I'm guessing p = fork() was what was meant, but this is the danger of compound statements.

Comment: yes it is p = fork() but the compiler gives an error (in the while u should write compare things not assigns a value)

Comment: It should be `while (i-- && ( p = fork() ) != 0)` - this way you convey the intent clearly and the compiler doesn't complain and the code doesn't depend on an uninitialized variable.

Comment: ok i wrote while (i-- && ( p = fork() ) != 0)  the output now :


i = 3, j = 36 
i = 0, j = 36 
i = -2, j = 24 
why i should be 0 beause while will be always true 
right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that was a typo, and `while (i-- && p == fork())` was really `while (i-- && (p = fork()))`, then the output depends on the OS scheduler.

The main process forks off processes with

- i=1  p=0  <-- process A, parent.p=A
- i=0  p=0  <-- process B, parent.p=B
- i=-1 p=B  <-- parent process, parent.p = B

Processes A and B do not continue the loop, because the `p=fork()` evaluates as false for them.

Each process adds 2 to j (which might as well be j=12). In summary:

```
A: i=+1 p=0    j=12
B: i= 0 p=0    j=12
P: i=-1 p=*B*  j=12
```

The cases where p=0, have i and j multiplied by 3, the ones with p!=0 (the parent process) have them multiplied by 2. This yields the following perfectly reasonable output for me:

```
i = -2, j = 24
i = 3, j = 36
i = 0, j = 36
```

(The order is going to be somewhat random)

As sharptooth pointed out, your code as written is simply producing random results, depending on a piece of uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 10):

`p` is uninitialized and *never changed*.

```
int j = 10, p;  //uninitialized
while (i-- && p == fork()) //comparison - no changes
if ( p < 0 ) exit(1); //comparison - no changes
if (p == 0) { //comparison - no changes
```

so `p` happens to store whatever value is there in the memory plus whatever the compiler assigns uninitialized variables to.

Comment: What about it?  Your code has a serious bug in it and will likely produce different output each time you run it.

Comment: @Bobj-C: the output is just arbitrary. Accessing an uninitialized variable such a `p` is undefined behavior, so don't expect anything consistent. Usually what you see as value of `p` is just random data as it was left over in that location. BTW a decent compiler should have told you that `p` is not initialized. Your teacher should at least have told you the appropriate warning options for the compiler on your teaching platform.

Comment: @Bobj-C: I'd guess that your `if (p < 0)` could trigger sometimes. But this is pure speculation, *undefined behavior* is just bad, just stop thinking of what could happen and correct the bug :)